# UICollectionView delegate is not responding when the UICollectionView is embedded within a UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UIScrollView`. The top half of the screen contains some labels and text fields. The lower half of the screen is the `UICollectionView`. The `UICollectionView` is embedded within the scrollview so that when the user scrolls down they are not limited to a half screen size collection view.

The collection view is presenting properly and the delegate is set as I've done countless times before.

I've purposely tested different solutions and if the collection view is added 'directly' to the UIViewController the `didSelectItemAtIndex` delegate method is called. When the collection view is added to a scrollView within the ViewController I get no response from the delegate method.

I have checked the Debug View Heirarchy and the ScrollView content size is sufficient to house the entire collectionView. The Debug view also shows the correct view as the `UICollectionViewDelegate`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having written the question I worked out my issue.

As part of the layout within the first half of the screen, I have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` added to the `UIScrollView` to `endEditing()` should the user click outside of a `UITextField`. This tap gesture was receiving the tap and 'ending it' before it was passed to the `UICollectionView`.